# creating recovery services vault in azure

Tags: azure, cloud

I am trying to create a "recovery services vault" service in azure manually but it is not showing me the resource.[image: The problem is highlighted in the fig]

please help we with the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking in the market place for the recovery services vault. If you search in the Azure portal you should be able to find it as below.

[image]